# Add Custom Domains in Github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

How to change http://user.github.io/repo to http://customdomain.com/myrepo in github pages?

I tried to going through the documantation and but it didn't talk about this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, to have a customized domain name, you have to create a file named `CNAME` in the root directory of your GitHub repository.
The file content should be something like this (this is just an example):

```
my-website.com
```

Instead of using `https://user.github.io/<repo-name>`, it will now redirect to `my-website.com`.
You **still** have to make a few other changes for this to work. Check out the GitHub Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

I hope that helped. Let me know if you need any more help. :)